Write a method that takes 3 integer as parameters, return true if they are equal, return false otherwise without using if statement
I am trying to write a method that compares three integers without using the if statement. I tried the switch statement, but it wouldn't work. Eclipse shows case expressions must be constants.
Here is a snippet of my code:
public boolean multipleValue(int n1, int n2, int n3)
{
    boolean result = false;

    switch (n1)
    {
    case num2:
    case num3:
        result = true;
        break;
    default:
        result = false;
    }
    
    return result;
}
```


Is this a coursework assignment? I imagine that your instructor wants you to use a compound Boolean expression.

There's actually an "easy" way to do this, try to think on your own and attempt it.  If you cannot, talk to your instructor or a classmate and ask for a hint.

Minor hint: try it first with a compound boolean expression as Tim suggests.  Use only one if statement. Then look carefully at the code.

This line checks if a is equal to b and if b is equal to c. If both conditions are true, it returns true; otherwise, it returns false.
return (a == b)&&(b == c); 

